# Accessing backend using Loopback Android SDK

Tags: android, api, server, loopback, angular-loopback

I am trying to access my backend API generated with Loopback's generator. I am using the in-memory database to store the data. Currently, I am testing it locally. When I try to create new instance of "Feature" I get this error in the callback:

```
D/AsyncHttpClient: Headers were overwritten! (Accept | application/json) overwrites (Accept | application/json)
V/AsyncHttpResponseHandler: Progress 210 from 210 (100%)
W/remoting.RestAdapter: HTTP request (string) failed: org.apache.http.client.HttpResponseException: Not Found
/xdesign.georgi.espc E/MainActivity: onError - org.apache.http.client.HttpResponseException: Not Found
```

This is a diagram of my models

[image]

My MainActicity looks like that:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private static final String TAG = MainActivity.class.getSimpleName();
private Model feature;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);







    RestAdapter adapter = new RestAdapter(getApplicationContext(), "http://10.0.2.2:8080/api");

    ModelRepository featureRepository = adapter.createRepository("Feature");
    feature = featureRepository.createObject(ImmutableBiMap.of("name","ANDROID_TEST"));

    feature.save(new VoidCallback() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess() {
            Log.e(TAG,"onSuccess");
        }

        @Override
        public void onError(Throwable t) {
            Log.e(TAG,"onError - " + t.toString());
        }
    });


}

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figured it out. I've got an onSuccess response when I changed the URL to the "server" to

```
http://10.0.2.2:3000/api
```

Apparently, we need to use port 3000 in order to get it to work.